# Acrescentar selected ao option após verificação de igualdade

Tags: php, laravel-blade

Tenho o seguinte select em um form no laravel:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('nivel') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="nivel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nível de acesso</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="nivel" value="{{ $detailpage->nivel }}" placeholder="Nivel de acesso">
            @if($detailpage->nivel != 2) <option value="2">Operacional</option>
            @else <option value="2" selected>Operacional</option>
            @endif
            @if($detailpage->nivel != 1) <option value="1">Administrativo</option>
            @else <option value="1" selected>Administrativo</option>
            @endif
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este é um exemplo, na prática serão várias categorias.

Existe alguma forma de colocar algo como:

```
<option value="1" @if($detailpage->nivel != 1) selected >Administrativo</option>
```

Ou seja de dizer que o item com o `value == nivel` sera `selected` e os outros não

Porém de maneira mais simples dq a que eu utilizei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não testado, mas pode parecer com algo assim

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('nivel') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="nivel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nível de acesso</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="nivel" value="{{ $detailpage->nivel }}" placeholder="Nivel de acesso">
 <option value="2"{{ $detailpage->nivel == 2 ? "selected='selected'" : "" }}>Operacional</option>
```

...

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou

Comment: Corrigi o != por ==